# no default browser set

Tags: browser

I have to replicate an issue and for this I need no browser set as the default browser even if its installed. Is it possible to have no browser set as default browser? If so, how should I do it?

Another question, if I have a couple of browsers installed, say IE and firefox and I set firefox as the default browser. Then, if I uninstall firefox, does IE automatically then become the default browser? or is there a condition possible where IE is the only installed browser and it is not the default browser? (I can't wait till I open the browser and it prompts me to set the default browser as I am using the browser programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this question is more relevant to superuser.com and less about programming, for suer you will find your answer there.
But anyhow,
Yes it is possible to have no default browser, and as far as i know, FireFox does not restore the default browser.